# Automator: Decode Decode64 selection and display output in a new TextEdit window

Tags: terminal, automator

I would like to display a service in a context menu for a selected text which is a base64 string. The service has to decode it to string with a base64 via terminal script and display an output in a new TextEdit window.

I have a service in an Automator app which has a script shell with input as arguments and command:

```
"$@" | base64 --decode
```

There is a connected "New TextEdit document action" to the shell script.

This display empty window

If I change the command to pbpaste | base64 --decode and I will copy a base64 string to clipboard then the service works correctly.

How to pipeline the input argument, which is a base64 selected string, to 'base64 --decode' command?

Comment: What is in "$@"? If this is just the text to decode you need to do something with it at the left side of the pipe (e.g. `echo $@ | ...`) or use `base64 --decode <<< "$@"`

Comment: @nohillside I missed echo. $@ should represent a selected text but it looks like this is a wrong placeholder for an input argument. How should I reference to an input argument?

Comment: Please edit your question then to reflect your actual code. It may even help to add a screenshot of the Automator flow.

Comment: Also: where is the input for the input argument coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is about TextEdit, but for anyone who would rather do this in BBEdit, you can create a TextFilter to process the selected text.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
  
def decode64(myString):
    return myString.decode('base64')

input = sys.stdin.read()
print decode64(input)
```

If you want to use python3, it's even easier:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import sys, base64

input = sys.stdin.read()
print base64.b64decode(input)
```

Save this to: `~/Library/Application Support/BBEdit/Text Filters`, then you can access it from the Text Filters menu.

Comment: I'm going to have to ask the same question and then answer it just for BBEdit, aren't I? <rolls eyes>

Answer (score 0):

if your **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* is set to e.g. **Service receives selected text in any application** / **Workflow receives text in any application**, then in the **Run Shell Script** *action* with **Pass input: as arguments** set, then the following line of *code* will return the decrypted text to an e.g. **New TextEdit Document** *action*:

<sup>Note: The use of *terms* separated with a **/** is to denote the difference between **Automator** prior to **macOS Mojave** and from it onwards.</sup>

```bash
base64 --decode <<< "$@"
```

As an alternative to using the **Run Shell Script** *action* and the **New TextEdit Document** *action*, by just using a **Run AppleScript** *action* to accomplish the task:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set encodedString to input as string
    
    set decodedString to ¬
        (do shell script "base64 --decode <<<" & encodedString's quoted form)
    
    tell application "TextEdit" to ¬
        make new document with properties {text:decodedString}
    
end run
```

Comment: echo $1 | base64 --decode works as well

Comment: @Adobels, Yes that too works, however, when working with a _string_ (the selected text), use a _here string_ `<<<` as it eliminates the needless use of: `echo |`.

Comment: Why both commands works 1. base64 --decode <<<  "$1"  2.  base64 --decode <<< $1 ?

Comment: @Adobels, as a general rule, _variables_ should be double-quoted to prevent globbing and word splitting. In other words, it's a _best practice_ and _more safe_.

Answer (score 0):

In Automator, you can set up a workflow as follows:

[image]

Pass in base64 data to stdin, as shown, and this will decode the data and write it into the front TextEdit window (opening the app and window, if required). This will overwrite the contents of that window; you can set it to append instead, or add an extra step to open a fresh window first.

Comment: $@ represents an input argument. I have found one in a blog post. I think that a correct way to access an argument is $1.

Comment: @Adobels: $@ returns the list of all input arguments; $1 returns the first input argument. I'm not sure which case the OP is trying to handle, but you're right that $1 would be better for a single input. But I suppose I should update it to handle multiple inputs correctly. I'll do that a bit later.

Comment: Selected text is an input to the shell script so I am interested only about single argument input. $@ I didn't new the difference between $@ and $1. thx

Comment: Did you not understand the question? The OP states "I would like to display a service in a context menu for a selected text which is a base64 string. The service has to decode it to string with a base64 via terminal script and display an output in a new TextEdit window." -- Your answer takes a _file_, not selected text,  as its input and replaces text, not opening it in a new  TextEdit document.

Comment: @user3439894: Meh! no, I missed that. Sloppy of me.  But that's an easy revision to make. I'll get on it.

Comment: My answer already covers it.

Comment: @user3439894: well, I already fixed it in mine.  If you want to download the screenshot I made and add it to your answer, I'll delete mine; no sense having duplicates, but the visual aid is useful.

Comment: That's okay, I didn't add a screen shot because the OP already stated what _actions_ were being used, **Run Shell Script** _action_ with **Pass input as arguments**, and  **New TextEdit Document**. So I didn't feel it was necessary to add a screen shot. While **to stdin** works too, your image doesn't match what the OP is using or what my answer has, but thanks for the offer.

Comment: @user3439894: You ought to think beyond the OP. Screenshots are helpful to a lot of people.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112363/discussion-between-user3439894-and-ted-wrigley).

Comment: Hey, I accidentally click the link to move to discussion.  I do use screen shots in my answer at times. This is not one I felt it was necessary as my answer is written so it doesn't  really need one. That said, your screen shot isn't doing what was asked in a **New TextEdit Document** _action_, not a **Set contents of TextEdit Document**.